# Run-time Error for a C program

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, converters

I found this program on the internet so I decided to try it, it converts a file to another type of file. I compiled and ran on my MAC OS X 10.9.1 through terminal, but it gave me a segmentation fault 11. What can I do to fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SRAM_SIZE       (32 * 1024)

typedef FILE* pfile;

static unsigned char SRAM[SRAM_SIZE];

int main(void)
{
    pfile in, out;
    register int i;

    in = fopen("input.sra", "rb");
    for (i = 0; i < SRAM_SIZE; i++)
        SRAM[i ^ ~0&3] = fgetc(in);
    fclose(in);
    out = fopen("output.sra", "wb");
    for (i = 0; i < SRAM_SIZE; i++)
        fputc(SRAM[i], out);
    fclose(out);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a general comment, it is often dangerous to run a program you find on the Internet without understanding what it does.  For instance, why does it do `SRAM[i ^ ~0&3] = ...`?  I would suggest running lldb.

Comment: @NG. It looks like it's trying to change the endianness of the SRAM image.

Comment: I wonder about `SRAM[i ^ ~0&3]`, why not just `SRAM[i ^ 3]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no error checking. Change:

```
in = fopen("input.sra", "rb");
for (i = 0; i < SRAM_SIZE; i++)
    SRAM[i ^ ~0&3] = fgetc(in);
fclose(in);
...
```

to:

```
in = fopen("input.sra", "rb");
if (in == NULL)
{
    printf("Unable to open 'input.sra'.\n");
    return -1;
}
for (i = 0; i < SRAM_SIZE; i++)
    SRAM[i ^ ~0&3] = fgetc(in);
fclose(in);
...
```

You should do the same for the output file too. There are a lot of ways this can fail and just blindly accessing an untested value is bad practice.

Comment: Also, the code seems to assume that the file size will be exactly (or at least) `SRAM_SIZE`. That would not cause a segfault though because AFAIK, `fgetc`/`fputc` return `EOF` if there was an error.

Comment: @SchighSchagh Actually, if file size is less, rest of the array should be filled with 0xFF, which may well be desired output (but hacky way to get it).

Comment: This helped, although I also tried another thing. I tried running the program through the terminal instead of just double-clicking the executable. Thanks!